# How to redirect index.php to another page properly via .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, indexing

Currently my htaccess file contains this rule, to redirect website.org/index.php to `website.org/en/home`

```
RewriteRule index.php /en/home [R=301]
```

However, currently also other `index.php` pages in deeper folders redirect!  e.g. `website.org/folder/index.php` redirects to `website.org/en/home`

How can I have that rule exclusively apply to the root, and no deeper folders?
Thanks very much.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^index.php /en/home [R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks! So, I guess that the `^` means that its the root of the server path?

Comment: No. ^ means start of the string. You are trying to match url path relative to folder in which .htaccess  is present. In this case its index.php.  In case of ur ex. url website.org/folder/index.php, index.php  match folder/index.php and do redirect. Now with ^index.php it doesn't matc folder/index.php as this url start with folder.